# mosquitto - allow_anonymous false shows connected message

Tags: mqtt, security, mosquitto, authentication

I have set the `acl_file` property in `/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf` to `/home/ubuntu/my.acl`. In the ACL file, I have `allow_anonymous false` to disallow connections from clients that do not have user name.

From MQTT Lens, I tried connecting to this broker without passing user name. I don't see a connect message immediately in the log. However, when I delete the connection from MQTT Lens, I see the message as connected followed by a disconnect message.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-42-207:/var/log/mosquitto$ tail -f mosquitto.log  
1527666604: New connection from 183.xx.xx.xx on port 1883.
1527666604: New client connected from 183.xx.xx.xx as lens_bWIkzTxFSc2BIIUQqqT35ipsiPV (c1, k120).
1527666746: Client lens_bWIkzTxFSc2BIIUQqqT35ipsiPV disconnected.
```

How can I confirm that `allow_anonymous false` actually denied the connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`allow_anonymous false` needs to be in the mosquitto.conf file not the acl file

IIRC the logging is delayed because of a minor bug in some versions of mosquitto because you are not driving any other load through the broker

Comment: :facepalm: I misread the `man mosquitto.conf` page!

Comment: Great answer, though I'm not sure I like `allow_anonymous false`.  Grrr!  ;)